# How to create an RDL using the report class generated from the RDL schema

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a project where we are creating a custom report generator for SSRS 2008R2. This project allows the user to select fields from a database and then create and store the RDL on the report server. 
For some of the initial proof of concept attempts we have been using XMLText writer to generate the XML file. While this works this seems to be very cumbersome and I don't have a lot of confidence in how the schema is being generated as being 100% bulletproof. A second attempt is actually using the generated class from the RDL as my object model. Where I am stuck here is there is almost zero documentation on how to use this object. [MSDN has a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337451%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on updating the model but it very basic in concept.

I'm looking for some guidance on the preferred approach. 
1) continue with the XML generation 
2) use the RDL object to create the reports 
3) I have also considered using the SSRS endpoint where a dummy report is created and stored on the server then using the RDL object model to update the report with the necessary fields, groups etc.

I haven't tested the third option but it seems as this would minimize the amount of coding for the creation of the document.

Thanks for any suggestions or ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just built a program that creates an SSRS report from a report template and a stored procedure.

I am using the RDLObjectModel to create the report. And RDLSerializer to allow saving the report to a file or the report server. I first load a report template from our report server through the SSRS web service to deserialize the server report into and RDLObjectModel. I then derive parameters for the report fields, and derive fields from the stored procedure to make a report dataset.

The problem that I ran into is that I wasn't able to serialize the report object to be able to save it to the server or to a file because in RDL2008 RDLSerializer is private. Then I came across an article that saved me a lot of headaches. http://ucodia.fr/2011/10/advanced-reporting-services-part2-rdl-serializer/

This is a much better approach that using XMLTextWriter. This should provide you enough to get things rolling.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I read this article as well and I think this is the approach I am going to use. I am opting not to use the RdlSerializer though as it is to heavy with dependencies on the other assemblies (as the article states). Instead I am using the approach suggested by this MSDN article to just use the XMLserialization to add the rdl back to the ssrs store http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337428%28v=sql.105%29.aspx Thanks again for clarifying the approach

Comment: I read that article as well. I started with trying to build my reports using the RDLSchema but it didn't seem very intuitive compared to using RDLObjectModel. As in [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f0a1d46-6d6d-4f67-b51e-06dbbbffacf9)... Code like this didn't look very friendly to me personally: 'Dim reportItems As List(Of ItemsChoiceType118) =  New List(Of ItemsChoiceType118)(m_report.ItemsElementName)' and  'DirectCast(m_report.Items(index), StringLocIDType).Value = "New Report Description"'

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem where I was using RdlObjectModel to create my report object but I was unable to serialize it.  There is a way to overcome that issue where you can still get instance of the RdlSerializer and call serialize method using reflection

You can find the implementation at the following [link](https://github.com/Ucodia/Blog-CustomReportingServices/blob/master/code/RdlSerializer.cs)

Comment: What's wrong in this answer, It is already implemented and working in a  production system I am working on