# Update reports using RDL Object model

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

This is in continuation to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283817/how-to-create-an-rdl-using-the-report-class-generated-from-the-rdl-schema)

for SSRS report generation using RDL Object model out of the box.

RDL schema is huge and so are the classes generated from xsd tool. There is so little or no documentation on how to manipulate the report definition using these classes. Also the reference http://ucodia.fr/2011/10/advanced-reporting-services-part2-rdl-serializer/ provided in original article takes no where

Please let me know if anyone can help me in dissecting and demystifying Reportdefinition

Comment: I was going off this tutorial.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337451.aspx Try it as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy. I have been searching on this topic for quiet some time now. Example is just updating description text. But we need to investigate on lot of other complex RDL elements to build meaningful reports.  Though microsoft exposed .net classes for RDL schema, they didn't provide easy APIs to update them too.  I am looking for some wrapper interface to modify RDL